# Rails - count foreign key records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables - users and requests.
The user table has many requests.
The requests records have user_id as a foreign key to the user table.

When I display the index for users, I'd like to display the number of requests for each user.

I'm sure this isn't close - but it might give you and idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
<td><%= user.sign_in_count %></td>
<td><%= @worequests.where("user_id = user.id").count %></td>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do it

```
 user.requests.count
```

Basically go through the user model to count all the requests it owns.